# ionic-datepicker - Como renderizar após o $http?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Boa tarde.

Seguinte...eu não sei ao certo se minha dúvida é sobre o Ionic ou sobre o AngularJs.

Estou implementando o código abaixo

```
$scope.datepickerObject = {
              titleLabel: 'Escolha a Data',  //Optional
              todayLabel: 'Hoje',  //Optional
              closeLabel: 'Fechar',  //Optional
              setLabel: 'Ok',  //Optional
              setButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
              todayButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
              closeButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
              inputDate: new Date(),  //Optional
              mondayFirst: true,  //Optional
              disabledDates: arDatas, //Optional
              weekDaysList: '', //Optional
              monthList: '', //Optional
              templateType: 'modal', //Optional
              showTodayButton: 'true', //Optional
              modalHeaderColor: 'bar-positive', //Optional
              modalFooterColor: 'bar-positive', //Optional
              from: new Date(), //Optional
              to: new Date(2018, 8, 25),  //Optional
              callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
                datePickerCallback(val);
              },
              dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy', //Optional
              closeOnSelect: true, //Optional
            };


            var datePickerCallback = function (val) {
          if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
            console.log('No date selected');
          } else {
            console.log('Selected date is : ', val)
            $scope.dataConsulta = val.toISOString().slice(0,10);
            this.dataConsulta = val.toISOString().slice(0,10);
          }
        };
```

Se eu coloco isso no JS, funciona maravilha, mas se eu coloco isso dentro de um $http, não funciona. Eu não sei como fazer para renderizar esse objeto após o Ajax finalizar.

Comment: "dentro de um $http" - você quer dizer 'dentro do callback em caso de sucesso de uma requisição $http', 'dentro de um arquivo .js que obtenho via $http', ou outra coisa? Clarifique sua questão um pouco mais, por favor.

Comment: Olá. desculpe se não fui claro. Vou tentar explicar.... se pegar esse bloco de código e colocar simplesmente no JS, dentro de um controller ele funciona perfeitamente. Entretanto, o que eu preciso é puxar as datas desabilitadas via Ajax de um banco de dados. Então, como esse plugin não tem nenhuma função SetDisabledData por exemplo, eu preciso pegar todo esse bloco de código e colocar dentro do success do $http. Quando eu faço isso, o HTML já foi renderizado antes da execução desse $http. Entendeu?

Comment: Já tentou apenas atualizar a coleção `$scope.datepickerObject.disabledDates[]` com as novas datas? Você não precisa recriar o controle.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Ele montou o calendário da forma adequada, porém não desabilitou as datas que coloquei na coleção $scope.datepickerObject.disabledDates = arDatas;

Comment: Acredito que assim você está trocando um objeto por outro (disabledDates = arDatas). Tente adicionar os valores recebidos ao objeto já existente (`$scope.datepickerObject.disabledDates.concat(arDatas)`)

Comment: Putz...não funciona também. Se eu inicializo o objeto com qualquer data desabilitada, funciona. Se eu quero adicionar mais datas depois de puxar do banco de dados, não funciona.